# Retrieving all links on a google search

Tags: c#, selenium, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to retrieve all links from a google search but without success ...

Im using Selenium + HTML Agility Pack

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(pageSource);

foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='rso']/div/div/div[1]/div/div/h3/a"))
{
     string href = link.GetAttributeValue("data-href", string.Empty);

     list.Add(href);
}

foreach (var item in list)
{
     Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Google HTML

```
<a href="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;q=&amp;esrc=s&amp;source=web&amp;cd=2&amp;cad=rja&amp;uact=8&amp;ved=0ahUKEwizrv_f06TWAhXLD5AKHa4pB1AQFgg3MAE&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rtl.de%2Fcms%2Fdsds-2017-das-sind-die-votingergebnisse-der-14-staffel-4112962.html&amp;usg=AFQjCNF_sFs_fpNAeBAPLitsVZbShMAhiw" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNF_sFs_fpNAeBAPLitsVZbShMAhiw','','0ahUKEwizrv_f06TWAhXLD5AKHa4pB1AQFgg3MAE','','',event)" data-href="http://www.rtl.de/cms/dsds-2017-das-sind-die-votingergebnisse-der-14-staffel-4112962.html">DSDS 2017: Das sind die Votingergebnisse der 14. Staffel - RTL.de</a>
```

I would like to extract the date-href but without success

Comment: What does the code do? How does that differ from what you **want** it to do?

Comment: They retrieve blank string

Comment: Are you sure that the xpath you are using is correct and valid on Google search page?

Comment: So, you're successfully able to find these anchor tags, and just can't retrieve the attribute `data-href`?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad, yes, that is right :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
string href = link.GetAttributeValue("data-href", string.Empty);
```

to

```
string href = link.Attributes("data-href").value;
```

It may works.

Comment: This did not work ... I checked in the debugger that there are only 7 attributes, and the data-href is not listed

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the problem that in this way you are finding all links. 
When you add `a[@data-href]` to the `XPath` of `SelectNodes` you'll select only the links with an actual data url attribute in them.

So it will become :

```cs
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='rso']/div/div/div[1]/div/div/h3/a[@data-href]")) 
{ 
    string href = link.GetAttributeValue("data-href", string.Empty); 
    list.Add(href); 
}
```